# How to "FTP jail" with Pure-FTPD?

Tags: ftp

I asked this a little bit ago, but instead of specifying Pure-FTPD I just said Apache. Per the answer to that question, I'm asking again with "Pure-FTPD" in the title this time.

I need to allow someone access to my VPS via FTP, but there are a number of directories that the person must not be allowed to view or modify. For example, something like this:

```
private_info_1
public_info_1
private_info_2
public_info_2
```

In this example, the FTP user would need to be allowed to do stuff in the public directories, but not the private ones.

How do I go about doing this with Pure-FTPD? I have cPanel and SSH access.

Comment: Just curious, how is apache relevant to the question? I am referring to the apache2 tag and the "apache server running pure-ftpd" statement.

Comment: @chutz - I guess nothing? I removed the apache tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use PureDB users, you could use the **-d homedirectory** option to chroot user to his home directory on account :

```
pure-pw useradd myuser -u ftpuser -g ftpgroup -d /home/ftp/myuser
```

To provide access to specific folders (often seen for webservers), use symlinks.

```
www -> /srv/www/myuser
```

[UPDATE]
Misread the post about jailing user.

You could either create another virtual user/group which would restrain filesystem access, although I'm not sure it would be safest thing to do (some people with better experience than me could answer).